# R function to select .png files into raynorcolour and extract meaningful values to save in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops

I am looking to use the R-package raynercolor to identify the colour (e.g. percent, colour, hue) of various fungi pictures that I have removed the background on and saved as .png files. I have 100's of photos to process. I would like to create a function that would pick these photos out of a folder, run raynercolor (I guess this would be a loop?) and then save the results as a dataframe with the file name and important outputs from raynercolor.

I am new to R studio and do not have experience writing my own functions or loops what so ever. If somebody cold direct me to a similar question or even help me write a code that would be amazing!
M

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360386152_Package_%27PUPMCR%27_Type_Package_Title_Color_Identification_of_Fungi_Based_on_Rayner_1970_and_Known_Fungal_Pigment_Association

```
library(PUPMCR)
raynercolor(system.file("fungi.png", package = "PUPMCR"))
```

Comment: Try `files <- list.files("path/to/your/folder", pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = TRUE); lapply(files, function(x) raynercolor(x))`

Comment: 'names(res) <- substr(files, 46, 67)
results <- bind_rows(res, .id = "column_label")' I added to your code to make a single data frame. With this I run into a problem if my file names are not all the same length, they will get cut off. Ultimately I would like to separate my file name into several columns (e.g. tree.id, date, week, isolate.id) based on the file name which looks something like this for example: 02R1_2wkJune2822_Iso1Bcopy.png

Comment: Do you want to rbind it i.e `do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) raynercolor(x)))`

Comment: @akrun yes exactly, but doing this merges all results without the ability to tell which colour is from which sample. So I managed to do the above and then added a column for sample identification called "column_label". I managed to also chop up my file names based on separators or numbers and letters to make meaningful factors for tree.id, date, isolate.id, etc.

Comment: You can add a column into the list i.e `do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, column_label = basename(files), lapply(files, raynercolor)))`

Comment: 'code' # runs the fungi colour identification automatically and spits out a data frame
files <- list.files("/path/NB", 
                    pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = TRUE); 
res <- lapply(files, function(x) raynercolor(x))
# only works if your .png file name is within the specified character lengths 
names(res) <- substr(files, 46, 67)
# pastes the .png fle name as a factor of a single large data frame 
results <- bind_rows(res, .id = "column_label")

# SEPERATING file name
results %>% separate(column_label, c("tree.id.iso", "wkdate","iso"), "_") -> results

Comment: Oh thank you! that is much cleaner than what I had!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, column_label = basename(files), 
    lapply(files, raynercolor)))
```